# Rubbersheeting of vector layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rubbersheeting

How do I [rubbersheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubbersheeting) two vector layers one with a projection like UTM WGS 84 Zone 45N using QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at VectorBlender, this is an experimental rubbersheeting plugin which does exactly what you are looking for:

https://github.com/olivierdalang/VectorBender

here is a screenshot of the [video](https://vimeo.com/96142479) showing how to use it:
[image]

https://vimeo.com/96142479