# How to create a transformation vector and apply it to a vector layer?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, affine-transformation

I have 3 layers I'm working with. I'll call them A,B and C.

Layer A - Satellite Imagery of location X (2017) (tiff)

Laber B - Satellite Imagery of location X (2021) (tiff)

Layer C - Vector Polygons of shapes I created based on imagery in Layer A. (geojson)

Layers A and B show the same geographical location, however are slightly off due to change in camera angle when photographing the earth, so features are slightly out of place. My ultimate goal is to take the vector polygons of Layer C, and relocate them onto the satellite imagery in Layer B. i.e. I want to create a transformation vector based on the difference between landmarks in layers A and B, then apply that transformation to the vector polygons in layer C, so layer C would align now with Layer B.

I'm using QGIS to achieve this. I've attempted to georeference Layer B to layer A, which creates a world file, but now I don't know 1.) if this is the best way to accomplish this goal, and 2.) if it is, how do I apply this world file to the vector polygons on Layer C?

Comment: In QGIS you should be able to rubbersheet if you use the plugin mentioned https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51868/rubbersheeting-of-vector-layers-in-qgis, if that doesn't work have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/georeferencing-vector-layer-with-control-points-using-qgis and see if some of those answers help.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, georeferencing vector layers is now native functionality in QGIS, see `Layer > Georeferencer > File > Open Vector`.

Comment: @Matt would you mind sharing which version of QGIS you are using?

Comment: 3.34, but it was added a few releases ago, I believe.